# Converting a Long to a varchar

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to convert a value of Long to a varchar so far I have approached it as convert to Long ->CLOB -> Varchar2:

```
INSERT into ALL_POSTAL_CODES (ZIP_CODE,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,ISO_COUNTRY,CITY,STATE, TIME_ZONE)
Select  ZIP_CODE,
        LATITUDE,
        TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(TO_LOB(LONGITUDE))),
        'USA',
        CITY,
        STATE,
        TIME_ZONE
from POSTAL_CODES
```

;

However I am hitting some syntax error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got LONG
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: `TO_CHAR(SUBSTR((TO_LOB(LONGITUDE0,0,255)))),` <-- one more `)` needed here

Comment: "missing right parentheses" should be pretty clear as to what the problem is.  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Just curious . . . Why not store this is a character representation?  What use is there converting the value to a LOB?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos or remove the extraneous parenthesis after `SUBSTR`...

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos & @D Stanley I have done both your suggestions same error msg returned

Comment: Why is it a LONG in the first place? That seems a completely inappropriate data type to store a longitude value. (I was going to ask if you are sure it is really a LONG and you aren't confusing the column name and type, but your response to Gordon's answer shows it is). Out of interest, what data type is your latitude column?

Comment: @AlexPoole Lat is a float, This is existing data from a legacy system. I got around the process by creating a temp table. If interested I can post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Temp table to get around this as there was no elegant solution

```
CREATE TABLE t1
  AS
  SELECT ZIP_CODE,
           to_lob(LONGITUDE) as LONGITUDE
    FROM POSTAL_CODES;

update ALL_POSTAL_CODES AP
Set AP.LONGITUDE = 
( select P.LONGITUDE
    from
    T1 P
    where 
    P.ZIP_CODE = AP.ZIP_CODE
     and
      rownum = 1 
    )
    where exists (
      select 
        null
      from 
        T1 P
      where 
        P.ZIP_CODE = AP.ZIP_CODE
      );

Drop table T1;
```